# Ignoring a key when looping through a sorted dictionary in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python and I'm assigning elements to an array utilizing a key with four elements.  I want to plot my arrays by looping through my sorted dictionary but I'd like to ignore one of the keys in the loop.  My code looks like this:

```
key = (process, temp, board, chip)

    #Do some stuff in a loop

for key in sorted(svmDict):
    #plot some things but don't sort with the variable chip
```

I found some articles for removing a specific key but in my case chip is actually a variable and I removing each key seems cumbersome and likely unnecessary.

Comment: I tried pop as well as the ignore list suggestion made below.  Again chip is a variable which is why I'm having a problem, if I wanted to remove a single item I know is in the list it works.

Comment: Why doesn't @rbierman's answer work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have 15 chip variables in my data set and three process variables, the current data I have uses all the same temperature and board.  If I am ignoring the chip variable I should output 3 graphs but I am still getting 15 graphs when I run the script.

Comment: Seems like a great lack of effort to solve or understand or even explain your OWN problem...

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to solve this before creating an account here to ask for help.  Thanks for your valuable insight and helpful comment.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 15 chip variables. Is `chip` the name of a list with 15 entries? Can you show me the `ignore_list` you tried to use?

Comment: I am looping through a directory and reading files, the variable chip is assigned each time a file is read and the variable is used to build a dictionary.  I want to plot all chips belonging to a single process on one plot so I want to ignore chip completely when I loop through the dictionary to create the plots.  I just started using python and I've done very little programming in the last decade so I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this well.  I wrote the code verbatim to your answer below.

Comment: I'm going to go about this a different way, I figured there was an elegant solution to ignoring part of a key in python but it seems like it's more effort than it's worth. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're not worried about speed I would just check whether or not you are at an acceptable key in the loop. You can directly check against one value you want to skip or make a list of values you want to skip

```
ignore_list = [chip]
for key in sorted(svmDict):
    if key not in ignore_list:
        #do the thing
```

Comment: if you use a `set` instead its `O(1)`

Comment: @JoranBeasley do you mean that the `ignore_list` should be a `set` so that searching for `key` in it is `O(1)`?